# Angular 5 Http Interceptor refreshing JWT token

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http-interceptors

I already have implemented logic of token saving, retrieving and I have refreshing call also. The problem is that when I intercept 403 in my HttpInterceptor, other calls that are made at the same time, also refresh the token. I would love to hold those calls until my token is refreshed. To create what I would call a 'semaphore' of requests.

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

private auth: AuthService;

constructor(private injector: Injector) {
}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);

    if(this.auth.isAuthenticated()){
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
            }
        });
    } else {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }

    return next.handle(request).catch(error => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
            console.log('refreshing token');

            // TODO: return Refresh Token here and hold other calls
        }

        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `HttpInterceptor` code?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question. Don't know why all the downvotes.

Comment: Are you sure that refreshing token after you get 401 is a good idea? This problem wouldn't be present if you would be using the JWT token expiration time to determine when to refresh before it has a chance to expire.

Comment: I think that for more security, the token should expire after some time.

Comment: Yes, it expires after some time but information about it expiration should be encoded within the token and therefore parsed and used in frontend for purpose of just in time token renewing.

Comment: @Bartando, could you let us know if the below solution worked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'm not able to setup an enviroment to test if this logic works properly, but I tried my best:

Your interceptor should be something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private auth: AuthService;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
  }

  setHeaders(request) {
    return function (token) {
      return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    }
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth
      .getToken()
      .map(this.setHeaders(request))
      .mergeMap(next.handle)
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          return this.auth.refreshToken()
            .map(this.setHeaders(request))
            .mergeMap(next.handle);
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }

}
```

And your AuthService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private refreshTokenCall;

  saveTokenInLocalStorage(token) {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
  }

  getToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
      return Observable.of(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    }

    return this.refreshToken();
  }

  refreshToken() {
    if (!this.refreshTokenCall) {
      this.refreshTokenCall = this.http.get(refreshTokenURL)
        // Maybe a .map() here, it depends how the backend returns the token
        .do(this.saveTokenInLocalStorage)
        .finally(() => this.refreshTokenCall = null);
    }
    return this.refreshTokenCall;
  }

}
```

I hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: I will try this and if it works, the bounty is yours :) Thank you

Comment: An explanation would make this an even better answer, please add one if you want. How are those calls waiting until the token is refreshed ?