# Difficulty Implementing an Intercepter to Handle Refreshing Tokens

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, jwt, angular5

I am building an Angular application that requires authentication. This is accomplished through tokens. The tokens have a short lifespan and need to be regularly refreshed. I have referenced this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060749/angular-5-http-interceptor-refreshing-jwt-token) , but I feel my needs and code structure are distinct (for example, I am not looking to "hold" the class and I have separate interceptors).

The primary purpose of one interceptor is to add the token to the header:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
        const refreshToken = this.authService.getRefreshToken();

        // If refresh token is expired, the user will need to relogin
        if(refreshToken == null || this.authService.checkTokenExpired(true)) {
            this.authService.logout();
            return next.handle(req);
        }

        // There is no token to send, continue.
        if (authToken == null || this.authService.checkTokenExpired()) {
            return next.handle(req);
        }   

        const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken } });    
        return next.handle(authReq);

    }

}
```

I have a separate interceptor to handle the "401" error:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const cBack = tap(res => {
            console.log("Refreshed");
            console.log("Token is " + this.authService.getToken());
            next.handle(req.clone
                ({ setHeaders: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.authService.getToken() } }));
        })
        return next.handle(req)
            .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (err.status == 401) {
                    this.authService.refresh()
                        .pipe(cBack).subscribe();

                }
                console.log(err);
                return _throw(err.message);
            });

    };

}
```

Where AuthService is the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private authURL: string = "http://localhost:8090/oauth/token";
  private loginPath : string = "/login";
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  redirectURL: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.redirectURL = "";
    this.isLoggedIn = this.getToken() != null;
  }
  login(user: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("grant_type", "password");
    data.append("username", user);
    data.append("password ", password);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa("web:secret")
      })
    };

    return this.http.post<AuthResponseModel>(this.authURL, data, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((r: AuthResponseModel) => {
          if (r.access_token) {
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", r.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", r.refresh_token);
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            return true;
          } 
        }
        ));
  };

  refresh() : Observable<boolean> {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    data.append("refresh_token", this.getRefreshToken());
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa("web:secret")
      })
    };

   return this.http.post<AuthResponseModel>(this.authURL, data, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
     map( r => {
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", r.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", r.refresh_token);
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        return true;
      })
    )

  }

  logout(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
    localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

  checkTokenExpired(checkRefresh = false) : boolean {
    if(checkRefresh) {  return decode(this.getRefreshToken()).exp < (Date.now().valueOf() / 1000); }
    return decode(this.getToken()).exp < (Date.now().valueOf() / 1000);
  }
  getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  }

  getRefreshToken() : string {
    return localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
  }


}
```

When the application receives a 401, it does properly send a request to refresh the token. I get the "Refreshed" and "Token is ..." `console.log` messages from the logging interceptor.  Additionally, it does place the token in local storage as it should. If I manually refresh the page, it actually works. However, my end goal is, when the application receives a 401, to refresh the token, and the resend the original request. The last step is the behavior that is not currently functioning.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT:

Version with retryWhen.

```
  let interceptor  = this;

return next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.authService.getToken() } })) 
.pipe(
    retryWhen(error$ => {
       return error$.pipe(
         mergeMap(error => {
           if (error.status === 401) {                  
             return interceptor.authService.refresh();
           } else {
             // re-throw
             _throw(error)
           }
         })
       );
    })        
 );
```

Comment: You're likely looking for `retryWhen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why you need a Auth and Logging interceptor, but I think you can do something like this:

```
class Interceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next
    .handle(req)
    .pipe(
       retryWhen(error$ => {
          return error$.pipe(
            mergeMap(error => {
              if (error.status === 401) {
                // fetch new token + retry
                return this.someService.refreshToken();
              } else {
                // re-throw
                _throw(error)
              }
            })
          );
       })        
    );
}
```